# IPFS: TypeError: o[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

Tags: ipfs

I'm trying to use IPFS, But when i am using the `ipfs.add('hello')` to add the hello into the IPFS it throws some error,

IPFS version used: 45.0.0,
Node Version used: v10.15.0

Here below is my full code:-

```
for await (const file of ipfs.add('hello')) {
        console.log(file)
     }
```

Comment: Your node version is *very* old. You should begin to update to the LTS version first: https://nodejs.org

Comment: I tested this and the code worked correctly in node.js version 14.0.0.